# How to view RMS file in J2ME?

Tags: java-me, midp, rms

I have J2ME app in which RMS is used as a database. I just wanted to know:

1. where is the Location of rms file in j2ME
2. How can we read it manually using any software and modify it?

I am asking this question since we can view `SQLite` database in Android in DDMS and we view and modify it in `SQLite` browser.

Answer (score 1):

Please Check following link they may help you :

http://www.roseindia.net/j2me/rms-midlet.shtml

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/J2ME/Readandwritetotherecordstore.htm

In android as we can see our applications database using sqlite browser ,In J2ME ther is nothing equivalent to sqlite browser.

The data contained in RMS can only be fetched programatically as shown in above links.

Comment: Thanks Shruti..But If I have large database and I just want to check the rms database then is it the only method to check its data by writing the whole program for retrieving once again

Comment: @Maverick.. If you just want to see data in database then anywhere you can call readrecord() method, which will give you all the records from database. You can get method readrecord() from google or from the above 2 links given by Shruti else I can also write the code for readrecoed() here. Please tell if you required then.

Answer (score 0):

For the S40 Series Nokia Phone, like model Nokia 3500 Classic, you can see RMS at same place where is your .Jar file available.

- for Windows base computer it will be in `Documents & settings/j2mewtk/2.5.2/appdb` appropriate type of emulator
- for linux base computer RMS resides in the following folder, 
  `/root/j2mewtk/2.5.2/appdb/` appropriate type of emulator

Comment: @Kalpan Thanks for your instant reply...Can we know where is its location is if we are developing app on the emulator